# query if a entry has changed since last check and continuously check for a time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

**The High Level Idea**:
I have a micro controller that can connect to my site via a http request...I want to feed the device a response as soon as a change is noted on the database...

Due to the the end device being a client ie micro controller...Im unaware of a method to pass the data to the client without having to set up port forwarding...which is heavily undesired ...The problem arise when trying send data from an external network to an internal one...Either A. port forwarding or B have the client device initiate the request which leads me to the idea of having the device send an http request to file that polls for changes

**Update**:

- Much Thanks to Ollie Jones. I have implimented some of his
  suggestions here.
- Jason McCreary suggested having a modified column which is a big
  improvement as it should increase speed and reliability ...Great
  suggestion! :)
- if the database being overworked is in question in this example
  maybe the following would work where...when the data is inserted into
  the database the changes are wrote to a file...then have the loop
  that continuously checks that file for an update....thoughts?

I have `table1` and i want to see if a specific row(based on a UID/key) has been updated since the last time i checked as well as continuously check for 60 seconds if the record bets updated...

I'm thinking i can do this using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database.

This database contains information about tables, views, columns, etc.

attempt at a solution:

```
    <?php 
$timer = time() + (10);//add 60 seconds
$KEY=$_POST['KEY'];
$done=0;

if(isset($KEY)){
//loign stuff
require_once('Connections/check.php');
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($hostname_check, $username_check, $password_check,$database_check);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
{ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }
//end login


$query = "SELECT data1, data2
FROM station 
WHERE client = $KEY
AND noted = 0;";

$update=" UPDATE station
SET noted=1
WHERE client = $KEY
AND noted = 0;";

while($done==0) {
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
   $update = mysqli_query($mysqli, $update);

   $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   if ($row_cnt > 0) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      echo  'data1:'.$row['data1'].'/';
      echo  'data2:'.$row['data2'].'/';
      print $row[0];
      $done=1;
   }
   else {
      $current = time();
      if($timer > $current){ $done=0; sleep(1); } //so if I haven't had a result update i want to loop back an check again for 60seconds
   else { $done=1; echo 'done:nochange';}//60seconds pass end loop
}}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
echo 'time:'.time();
}
else {echo 'error:nokey';}
?>
```

Is this an adequate method and suggestions to improve the speed as well as improve the reliability

Comment: Why not just have a *modified* column in the table and check it?

Comment: what's "continously check" mean? "look once, then keep hammering the database with repetitive checks"?

Comment: @MarcB Yes. that is what i mean ... a sleep(2); couldn't hurt i guess

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I honestly didn't think of this as a method of checking to see if a change has occurred then reset the modified column back after i post the change....hmm I like it though I'm still interested in how to continuously check the database

Comment: What's your high-level goal, you may be going about this all wrong.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I have a micro controller that can connect to my site via a http request...I want to feed the device a response as soon as a change is noted on the database...

Comment: @JasonMcCreary is that too high level?

Comment: That's fine. Why can't the code register the change? Why even poll the database?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary im not sure i follow you... by code you mean the server correct.. the change occurs in the database so .... Im a little confused what you mean

Comment: You're trying to use MySQL as the hub of a notification engine. You're proposing to build software that makes it work that way.  There's nothing wrong with that. BUT, MySQL doesn't have any kind of "on change   send message" functionality. You're proposing to implement that in PHP. That's ok, but your php program will need to hammer on MySQL to poll for changes.

You'd best be very careful about the performance of your polling query, and diligent about the latency you need. 

Or, look at using a message-queue system instead, if this needs to scale up.

Comment: @OllieJones your are 100% correct! im not aware of a superior method given my unique circumstance.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary YES! Im seeing some light here please continue

Comment: @OllieJones What if when the data was inserted I wrote the change to a file...then have the loop that continuously checks that file for an update....thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your application correctly, your client is a microcontroller. It issues an HTTP request to your php / mysql web app once in a while. The frequency of that request is up to the microcontroller, but but seems to be once a minute or so.

The request basically asks, "dude, got anything new for me?"

Your web app needs to send the answer, "not now" or "here's what I have."

Another part of your app is providing the information in question. And it's doing so asynchronously with your microcontroller (that is, whenever it wants to).

To make the microcontroller query efficient is your present objective.

(Note, if I have any of these assumptions wrong, please correct me.)

Your table will need a `last_update` column, a `which_microcontroller` column or the equivalent, and a `notified` column. Just for grins, let's also put in `value1` and `value2` columns. You haven't told us what kind of data you're keeping in the table.

Your software which updates the table needs to do this:

```
 UPDATE theTable 
   SET notified=0, last_update = now(), 
       value1=?data, 
       value2?=data
 WHERE which_microcontroller = ?microid
```

It can do this as often as it needs to.  The new data values replace and overwrite the old ones.

Your software which handles the microcontroller request needs to do this sequence of queries:

```
  START TRANSACTION;

 SELECT value1, value2
   FROM theTable 
  WHERE notified = 0
    AND microcontroller_id = ?microid
    FOR UPDATE;

 UPDATE theTable
    SET notified=1
  WHERE microcontroller_id = ?microid;

 COMMIT;
```

This will retrieve the latest value1 and value2 items (your application's data, whatever it is) from the database, if it has been updated since last queried.  Your php program which handles that request from the microcontroller can respond with that data.

If the SELECT statement returns no rows, your php code responds to the microcontroller with "no changes."

This all assumes microcontroller_id is a unique key. If it isn't, you can still do this, but it's a little more complicated.

Notice we didn't use last_update in this example.  We just used the notified flag.

If you want to wait until sixty seconds after the last update, it's possible to do that.  That is, if you want to wait until value1 and value2 stop changing, you could do this instead.

```
  START TRANSACTION;

 SELECT value1, value2
   FROM theTable 
  WHERE notified = 0
    AND last_update <= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND
    AND microcontroller_id = ?microid
    FOR UPDATE;

 UPDATE theTable
    SET notified=1
  WHERE microcontroller_id = ?microid;

 COMMIT;
```

For these queries to be efficient, you'll need this index:

```
  (microcontroller_id, notified, last_update)
```

In this design, you don't need to have your PHP code poll the database in a loop.  Rather, you query the database when your microcontroller checks in for an update/

Comment: You nailed 99% of it and I thank you so much for your response.So why the loop...I want the system to be as fast as possible...Rather then have the client continuously send a request I thought it would be much more efficient and quicker to have the connection open for 60 seconds while a php script checks if anything has changed in the loop.If nothing has the connection is closed and then immediately following a new request is sent from the client. To take some of the stress of the database when a record is updated a change log file could be updated.. the loop could just check the log file...

Comment: I really do appreciate your response and great detail!

Comment: Ollie id love to hear your response to my comment.

Comment: It's really not a good idea to do a sleep()-style call in web server software. It probably doesn't matter very much if you only have one microcontroller (or other client). But holding connections open while sleep()ing will mess up the scalability of your system. Believe it or not, it's probably more efficient to have the microcontroller poll back later, than it is to make it wait.

Comment: SO better to have the micro controller ask 50 times a minute then just a while loop like i suggested?

Comment: I adjusted the above code to reflect several of your suggestions...What if I removed the sleep but kept the loop. Speed is of some importance to me...Thanks Again for your help ...Its oten hard to come by good advice.

Comment: In your case, I believe "speed" means latency between the time a change appears in your MySQL server and the time you send that message to the microcontroller, correct?  (Pro-tip: don't use the word "speed" when specifying performance: it's quite vague.) If you're using a DBMS for this, you need to poll it = hammer on it. So it's a problem technologically for you to specify a very low latency. A latency of one second will work. A tenth of a second is really going to hurt.  If you only have one ucontroller, sure, do the sleeps, etc, in your web app.

Answer (score 0):

If **all `table1` changes** are *handled* by PHP, then there's no reason to *poll* the database. Add the logic you need at the PHP level when you're updating `table1`.

For example (assuming OOP):

```
public function update() {
  if ($row->modified > (time() - 60)) {
    // perform code for modified in last 60 seconds
  }

  // run mysql queries
}
```

Comment: What if when the data was inserted I wrote the change to a file...then have the loop that continuously checks that file for an update..

Comment: Why do you need the file? Can't you perform the actions needed at the time you identified the change?

Comment: due to the the end device being a client ie micro controller...Im unaware of a method to pass the data to the client without having to set up port forwarding...which is heavily undesired ...The problem arise when trying send data from an external network to an internal one...Either A. port forwarding or B have the client device initiate the request which leads me to the idea of having the device send an http request to file that polls for changes....